# boost::geometry 3D polygon intersection compilation errors

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

This code snippet works fine in 2D version, but doesn't compile in 3D version:

```
namespace bg = boost::geometry;

typedef bg::model::point<double, 3, bg::cs::cartesian> Point3D;
typedef bg::model::polygon<Point3D>                    Poly3D;

Poly3D         p0, p1;
vector<Poly3D> result;

bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0 0, 0 1 1, 1 0 0, 0 0 0))", p0);
bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0 0.5, 0 11 0.5, 11 0 0.5, 0 0 0.5))", p1);

bg::intersection(p0, p1, result);
```

with this template error:

```
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost/geometry/core/coordinate_dimension.hpp(89): error C2338: ( boost::mpl::equal_to < geometry::dimension<Geometry>, boost::mpl::int_<Dimensions> >::type::value )
...
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with `intersection` call? My application is to find intersection of planar polygons. I can see that in general case `Poly3D` doesn't have to be planar, so it can be the source of this error. Is there a way to define a planar 3D polygon type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erm. The compiler is telling you that the algorithm invoked is invalid for 3 dimensions... The programmers made this explicitely clear (area.hpp):

```
    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT( (geometry::concept::AreaStrategy<Strategy>) );
    assert_dimension<Ring, 2>();
```

So. Yeah. Can't use `intersection` to cross two planar polygons. I'm pretty sure with a bit of maths you can do two projections which would lead to two intersections that together give you the information you're after.

Comment: `programmers made this explicitely clear` - explicitly clear in templatese, which is a pretty muddled notation itself ;-)